# Failed to Connect to PPTP VPN Server on Ubuntu

Tags: pptpd

I am trying to connect to a PPTP VPN server. The same config works fine in Windows but fails in Ubuntu 12.10.  It must be some configuration issue.

```
sudo pptpsetup --create MYVPN --server xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx --username username --password password
```

Everything is setup correctly. But then when I try to actually run the VPN I get this:

```
$ sudo pppd call MYVPN updetach
Using interface ppp1
Connect: ppp1 <--> /dev/pts/2
LCP: timeout sending Config-Requests
Connection terminated.
Modem hangup
```

When I do this for more details:

```
tail -n 30 /var/log/syslog | grep -i ppp

Mar 18 06:33:08 tp pppd[5082]: pppd 2.4.5 started by root, uid 0
Mar 18 06:33:08 tp pppd[5082]: Using interface ppp1
Mar 18 06:33:08 tp pppd[5082]: Connect: ppp1 <--> /dev/pts/2
Mar 18 06:33:08 tp NetworkManager[988]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp1, iface: ppp1)
Mar 18 06:33:08 tp NetworkManager[988]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp1, iface: ppp1): no ifupdown configuration found.
Mar 18 06:33:08 tp NetworkManager[988]: <warn> /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp1: couldn't determine device driver; ignoring...
Mar 18 06:34:18 tp pppd[5082]: LCP: timeout sending Config-Requests
Mar 18 06:34:18 tp pppd[5082]: Connection terminated.
Mar 18 06:34:18 tp NetworkManager[988]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices removed (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp1, iface: ppp1)
Mar 18 06:34:18 tp pppd[5082]: Modem hangup
Mar 18 06:34:18 tp pptp[5084]: anon warn[decaps_hdlc:pptp_gre.c:216]: pppd may have shutdown, see pppd log
Mar 18 06:34:18 tp pppd[5082]: Exit.
```

Why is it not connecting?  It works fine from Windows, so it must be something with Ubuntu 12.10 settings...

**EDIT:**

```
sudo pppd call MYVPN debug dump logfd 2 updetach
```

Is there any information about how to utilize this information to see what might have gone wrong?

```
    pppd options in effect:
debug       # (from command line)
updetach        # (from command line)
logfd 2     # (from command line)
dump        # (from command line)
noauth      # (from /etc/ppp/peers/MYVPN)
name username       # (from /etc/ppp/peers/MYVPN)
remotename MYVPN        # (from /etc/ppp/peers/MYVPN)
        # (from /etc/ppp/peers/MYVPN)
pty pptp xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx --nolaunchpppd     # (from /etc/ppp/peers/MYVPN)
crtscts     # (from /etc/ppp/options)
        # (from /etc/ppp/options)
asyncmap 0      # (from /etc/ppp/options)
lcp-echo-failure 4      # (from /etc/ppp/options)
lcp-echo-interval 30        # (from /etc/ppp/options)
hide-password       # (from /etc/ppp/options)
ipparam MYVPN       # (from /etc/ppp/peers/MYVPN)
nobsdcomp       # (from /etc/ppp/peers/MYVPN)
nodeflate       # (from /etc/ppp/peers/MYVPN)
noipx       # (from /etc/ppp/options)
using channel 27
Using interface ppp1
Connect: ppp1 <--> /dev/pts/2
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0x4e812c17> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0x4e812c17> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0x4e812c17> <pcomp> <accomp>]
rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x0 <mru 1400> <auth chap MD5> <magic 0x27f847d4> <pcomp> <accomp> <callback CBCP> <mrru 1614> <endpoint [local:f8.7d.55.9e.60.00.42.53.ac.37.23.b6.c9.f4.6d.2f.00.00.00.00]> < 17 04 01 00>]
sent [LCP ConfRej id=0x0 <callback CBCP> <mrru 1614> < 17 04 01 00>]
rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <mru 1400> <auth chap MD5> <magic 0x27f847d4> <pcomp> <accomp> <callback CBCP> <mrru 1614> <endpoint [local:f8.7d.55.9e.60.00.42.53.ac.37.23.b6.c9.f4.6d.2f.00.00.00.00]> < 17 04 01 00>]
sent [LCP ConfRej id=0x1 <callback CBCP> <mrru 1614> < 17 04 01 00>]
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0x4e812c17> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0x4e812c17> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0x4e812c17> <pcomp> <accomp>]
rcvd [LCP ConfAck id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0x4e812c17> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0x4e812c17> <pcomp> <accomp>]
rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x4 <mru 1400> <auth chap MD5> <magic 0x27f847d4> <pcomp> <accomp> <callback CBCP> <mrru 1614> <endpoint [local:f8.7d.55.9e.60.00.42.53.ac.37.23.b6.c9.f4.6d.2f.00.00.00.00]> < 17 04 01 00>]
sent [LCP ConfRej id=0x4 <callback CBCP> <mrru 1614> < 17 04 01 00>]
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0x4e812c17> <pcomp> <accomp>]
rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x6 <mru 1400> <auth chap MD5> <magic 0x27f847d4> <pcomp> <accomp> <endpoint [local:f8.7d.55.9e.60.00.42.53.ac.37.23.b6.c9.f4.6d.2f.00.00.00.00]>]
sent [LCP ConfAck id=0x6 <mru 1400> <auth chap MD5> <magic 0x27f847d4> <pcomp> <accomp> <endpoint [local:f8.7d.55.9e.60.00.42.53.ac.37.23.b6.c9.f4.6d.2f.00.00.00.00]>]
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0x4e812c17> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0x4e812c17> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0x4e812c17> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0x4e812c17> <pcomp> <accomp>]
rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x9 <mru 1400> <auth chap MD5> <magic 0x27f847d4> <pcomp> <accomp> <endpoint [local:f8.7d.55.9e.60.00.42.53.ac.37.23.b6.c9.f4.6d.2f.00.00.00.00]>]
sent [LCP ConfAck id=0x9 <mru 1400> <auth chap MD5> <magic 0x27f847d4> <pcomp> <accomp> <endpoint [local:f8.7d.55.9e.60.00.42.53.ac.37.23.b6.c9.f4.6d.2f.00.00.00.00]>]
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0x4e812c17> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0x4e812c17> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0x4e812c17> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0x4e812c17> <pcomp> <accomp>]
rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0xc <mru 1400> <auth chap MD5> <magic 0x27f847d4> <pcomp> <accomp> <endpoint [local:f8.7d.55.9e.60.00.42.53.ac.37.23.b6.c9.f4.6d.2f.00.00.00.00]>]
sent [LCP ConfAck id=0xc <mru 1400> <auth chap MD5> <magic 0x27f847d4> <pcomp> <accomp> <endpoint [local:f8.7d.55.9e.60.00.42.53.ac.37.23.b6.c9.f4.6d.2f.00.00.00.00]>]
LCP: timeout sending Config-Requests
Connection terminated.
Modem hangup
Waiting for 1 child processes...
  script pptp xxx.xxx.xx.xxx --nolaunchpppd, pid 6815
Script pptp xxx.xxx.xx.xxx --nolaunchpppd finished (pid 6815), status = 0x0
```

Comment: execute "sudo pppd call MYVPN debug dump logfd 2 nodetach" to see more information

Comment: many thanks. I have updated the question. How can I utilize this information to find the problem?

Comment: In my case the problem was with the ISP router, I'd have to configure the "PPTP PassThrough" to enable those connections. :O

Answer (score 15):

I experienced exactly the same issue on my VPN, which started after installing Utopic HWE kernel 3.16.0 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

After researching I found the root cause of the issue:

```
Using interface ppp0
Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/pts/4
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <auth chap MS-v2> <magic0x792e9abe> <pcomp> <accomp>]  
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <auth chap MS-v2> <magic 0x792e9abe> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <auth chap MS-v2> <magic 0x792e9abe> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <auth chap MS-v2> <magic 0x792e9abe> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <auth chap MS-v2> <magic 0x792e9abe> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <auth chap MS-v2> <magic 0x792e9abe> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <auth chap MS-v2> <magic 0x792e9abe> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <auth chap MS-v2> <magic 0x792e9abe> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <auth chap MS-v2> <magic 0x792e9abe> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <auth chap MS-v2> <magic 0x792e9abe> <pcomp> <accomp>]
LCP: timeout sending Config-Requests
Connection terminated.
Modem hangup
```

The root cause was that 2 required netfilter kernel modules are not loaded during boot:

```
nf_conntrack_pptp
nf_conntrack_proto_gre
```

Solution: load the nf_conntrack_pptp module, the latter is its dependency and will be loaded automatically.

```
sudo modprobe nf_conntrack_pptp
```

References:

- http://pptpclient.sourceforge.net/howto-diagnosis.phtml#lcp_timeout
- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2182790

Comment: these filters were required on the VPN server node or client ?

Comment: @Ahmed On the server that runs pptpd

Answer (score 5):

I have googled 'LCP: timeout sending Config-Requests' for a while, and can't find a 
solution. Some posts said it is related with router setting, but I have my MAC and android phone connected without problem, so it is not my router's problem.

After poking ppp setting around, I find solution working for me.
Edit /etc/ppp/options, enable option silent, then problem solved.

```
    # With this option, pppd will not transmit LCP packets to initiate a
    # connection until a valid LCP packet is received from the peer (as for
    # the "passive" option with old versions of pppd).
    silent
```

I use Ubuntu 12.04, and setup VPN from GUI

Comment: This helped me with my Mac as a server and Android as a client connection. I was using iVPN and had to create the options file, but after doing that and restarting iVPN, it worked! Thanks for the tip.

Comment: These settings did not work for me, on raspberry pi using it as vpn server (pptpd)

Answer (score 5):

For the majority of distributions you must load the `nf_conntrack_pptp` and `nf_conntrack_proto_gre` kernel modules  for certain PPTP/VPN servers. This can be done with:

```
$ sudo modprobe nf_conntrack_pptp
```

(`nf_conntrack_proto_gre` is loaded automatically as a dependency of `nf_conntrack_pptp`)

Comment: 1. Only worked in reverse order: `modprobe nf_conntrack_pptp nf_conntrack_proto_gre`. 2. 
This helps me, but only for one VPN connection. After the client disconnects, the modules need to be loaded again.  I only found a bruteforce solution: http://askubuntu.com/questions/599523/i-finally-got-pptp-working-but-where-insert-command-to-autostart-it, do you have a better one?

Comment: Instead of typing the commands in the terminal, you could make an Icon-Script-Launcher that loads the modules. This way, you should click on before you activate the VPN connection. If there is a better way: Unfortunately I do not know why the modules get unloaded after each disconnection. I would like this not to happen obviously. If I find a solution I will let you know. So far for me they do not get unloaded (not using ubuntu). However, I suspect that this happened to me also, some months ago.

Answer (score 2):

> Mar 18 06:34:18 tp pppd[5082]: LCP: timeout sending Config-Requests

This may be an issue with GRE (ip 47) protocol. Check this page:

http://pptpclient.sourceforge.net/howto-diagnosis.phtml#lcp_timeout

Also try to connect to 1723 on pptp server:

```
telnet "server-ip-or-host" 1723
```

If this port is not blocked I recommend to check firewall settings on computer and router(some routers have pptp/gre passthrough option)

Comment: +1 for passthrough. For some routers you need to enable pptp and/or ipsec passthrough in your router settings and add your machine's mac address to the passthrough list.

Answer (score 1):

Did not helped any other solution but i found out another solution. Had the same error that is trying to connect but is timing out.

**Debug**

I did `$ tail -f /var/log/syslog` and saw a around 10 lines of these messages:

> Apr 21 22:20:37 user-pc kernel: [ 3008.652602]
>   [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlxxxxxxxxxxxx OUT=
>   MAC=00:a0:a0:00:00:00:a0:a0:a0:00:00:00:00:00 SRC=111.222.333.444
>   DST=111.222.333.444 LEN=54 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=59 ID=43069 PROTO=47

And after that a failure message

> Apr 21 22:20:38 tp pppd[5082]: LCP: timeout sending Config-Requests

**Fix**

Since I saw [UFW BLOCK] I found out that UFW (firewall) is blocking incoming traffic. Then added rule to UFW to allow the traffic from my VPN client with this command:

```
$ sudo ufw allow proto gre from [ip_of_pptp_server]
$ sudo service ufw restart
```

then I tried to reconnect PPTP VPN and it worked.

Comment: This solution worked for me.. but before trying this option i tried "sudo modprobe nf_conntrack_pptp nf_conntrack_proto_gre"

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION :** We also had the same problem. The issue is because of the mismatch of pptp client version & ubuntu version. Instead of apt-get we manually need to download & compile the source.

Download the latest version of pptp client source from [official website](http://pptpclient.sourceforge.net/#download)

```
cd /pptp-1.9.0
make
cp pptp /usr/sbin
```

After these steps, VPN is connecting.

Comment: If the Ubuntu package does not work due to a version mismatch, please file a bug report so it can be fixed.  Ubuntu is only as good as we volunteers make it.

Answer (score 0):

We were getting this error (The VPN connection 'MY-VPN' failed because the VPN service stopped unexpectedly) because we allowed ufw. like

```
sudo ufw allow 1433
```

Once we disabled ufw using the following command, the VPN connected successfully again.

```
sudo ufw disable
```