# I finally got pptp working.... but where insert command to autostart it?

Tags: lubuntu, vpn, autostart

I was looking for a solution and finally found,I have to run in terminal:
`sudo modprobe nf_conntrack_pptp`

I don't know what it is, what this command is doing, I know only that i have to  run  this command every time to keep VPN working on my Lubuntu 14.10.

Anyone can help why I have to run this command every time?

And why I have to do it when I've configured VPN properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your terminal and type as

`gedit /etc/rc.local`

Then add following line at ending

`nohup sudo modprobe nf_conntrack_pptp`

Then save and close your file.

Restart your Ubuntu and check.

Let us know if any issues.

Comment: Credit goes to All the linux sources.

Comment: I need to reload the modules after every client disconnection. `modprobe` is successful, so `nohup` doesn't repeat after a single success.