# Can't connect to PPTP VPN server

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn, ppp

I'm facing issues when trying to connect to a windows vpn server. On my win 8 I can connect without problem; when I go to my ubuntu I can't connect to the vpn. It is the same desktop, so the same router.

I checked the router properties, it has PPTP PassThrough property enabled.

I have tried several options researching this and other forums, for example I have applied all these items but still same problem:
[Failed to Connect to PPTP VPN Server on Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/269399/failed-to-connect-to-pptp-vpn-server-on-ubuntu)

This is my /var/log/syslog:

```
Jun 29 16:14:41 myPC NetworkManager[930]: <info> Starting VPN service 'pptp'...
Jun 29 16:14:41 myPC NetworkManager[930]: <info> VPN service 'pptp' started (org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.pptp), PID 4073
Jun 29 16:14:41 myPC NetworkManager[930]: <info> VPN service 'pptp' appeared; activating connections
Jun 29 16:14:41 myPC NetworkManager[930]: <info> VPN plugin state changed: starting (3)
Jun 29 16:14:41 myPC NetworkManager[930]: <info> VPN connection 'AMN' (Connect) reply received.
Jun 29 16:14:41 myPC pppd[4077]: Plugin /usr/lib/pppd/2.4.5/nm-pptp-pppd-plugin.so loaded.
Jun 29 16:14:41 myPC pppd[4077]: pppd 2.4.5 started by root, uid 0
Jun 29 16:14:41 myPC pppd[4077]: Using interface ppp1
Jun 29 16:14:41 myPC pppd[4077]: Connect: ppp1 <--> /dev/pts/11
Jun 29 16:14:41 myPC NetworkManager[930]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp1, iface: ppp1)
Jun 29 16:14:41 myPC NetworkManager[930]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp1, iface: ppp1): no ifupdown configuration found.
Jun 29 16:14:41 myPC NetworkManager[930]: <warn> /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp1: couldn't determine device driver; ignoring...
Jun 29 16:14:41 myPC pptp[4081]: nm-pptp-service-4073 log[main:pptp.c:314]: The synchronous pptp option is NOT activated
Jun 29 16:14:41 myPC pptp[4020]: anon log[ctrlp_rep:pptp_ctrl.c:251]: Sent control packet type is 7 'Outgoing-Call-Request'
Jun 29 16:14:41 myPC pptp[4020]: anon log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:858]: Received Outgoing Call Reply.
Jun 29 16:14:41 myPC pptp[4020]: anon log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:897]: Outgoing call established (call ID 1, peer's call ID 31406).
Jun 29 16:15:07 myPC pptp[4020]: anon log[logecho:pptp_ctrl.c:677]: Echo Request received.
Jun 29 16:15:07 myPC pptp[4020]: anon log[ctrlp_rep:pptp_ctrl.c:251]: Sent control packet type is 6 'Echo-Reply'
Jun 29 16:15:09 myPC pptp[4020]: anon log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:912]: Received Call Clear Request.
Jun 29 16:15:11 myPC kernel: [ 2254.427709] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:8c:04:ff:9b:5b:13:08:00 SRC=192.168.0.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=28 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=0 PROTO=2 
Jun 29 16:15:11 myPC kernel: [ 2254.427961] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:8c:04:ff:9b:5b:13:08:00 SRC=192.168.0.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=0 PROTO=2 
Jun 29 16:15:12 myPC pppd[4077]: LCP: timeout sending Config-Requests
Jun 29 16:15:12 myPC pppd[4077]: Connection terminated.
Jun 29 16:13:07 myPC avahi-daemon[920]: message repeated 6 times: [ Withdrawing workstation service for ppp0.]
Jun 29 16:15:12 myPC avahi-daemon[920]: Withdrawing workstation service for ppp1.
Jun 29 16:15:12 myPC NetworkManager[930]: <warn> VPN plugin failed: 1
Jun 29 16:15:12 myPC NetworkManager[930]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices removed (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp1, iface: ppp1)
Jun 29 16:15:12 myPC pppd[4077]: Modem hangup
Jun 29 16:15:12 myPC pptp[4081]: nm-pptp-service-4073 warn[decaps_hdlc:pptp_gre.c:204]: short read (-1): Input/output error
Jun 29 16:15:12 myPC pptp[4081]: nm-pptp-service-4073 warn[decaps_hdlc:pptp_gre.c:216]: pppd may have shutdown, see pppd log
Jun 29 16:15:12 myPC pptp[4020]: anon log[callmgr_main:pptp_callmgr.c:234]: Closing connection (unhandled)
Jun 29 16:15:12 myPC pptp[4020]: anon log[ctrlp_rep:pptp_ctrl.c:251]: Sent control packet type is 12 'Call-Clear-Request'
Jun 29 16:15:12 myPC pppd[4077]: Exit.
Jun 29 16:15:12 myPC NetworkManager[930]: <warn> VPN plugin failed: 1
Jun 29 16:15:12 myPC NetworkManager[930]: <warn> VPN plugin failed: 1
Jun 29 16:15:12 myPC NetworkManager[930]: <info> VPN plugin state changed: stopped (6)
Jun 29 16:15:12 myPC NetworkManager[930]: <info> VPN plugin state change reason: 0
Jun 29 16:15:12 myPC NetworkManager[930]: <info> Policy set 'Wired connection 1' (eth0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS.
Jun 29 16:15:12 myPC NetworkManager[930]: <warn> error disconnecting VPN: Could not process the request because no VPN connection was active.
Jun 29 16:15:17 myPC NetworkManager[930]: <info> VPN service 'pptp' disappeared
```

It seems to be an issue with GRE, but I'm new on linux and don't know anything on networks.. so, how can I fix this problem?

---

After shutting down the pc and turning it on again the following day, it is failing again. I have already reinstalled ppp but the same problem is faced:

```
LCP: timeout sending Config-Requests
```

Any thought?

Comment: same problem, could not resolve it yet

Answer (score 2):

Ok don't worry.. I did the best resolution problem..

Unistall PPP from Ubuntu Software center.. and then reinstall everything with:

```
sudo apt-get -f install ppp network-manager-pptp pppconfig pppoeconf pptp-linux
```

I created a new VPN connection from gui, and set the MPPE option to true. And it worked fine! =)

Comment: Doesn't work for me and also makes things worse. ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Does not work in ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue. I found out that after I recently played with firewall configuration, there were some rules still enabled. After I cleaned up all the firewall rules (using iptables, see https://serverfault.com/questions/200635/best-way-to-clear-all-iptables-rules), I could connect to the VPN again.

Comment: Does not work in ubuntu 20.04